# How to create a new .storyboard file in a blue folder in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, directory, storyboard

When I try to create a new file by right clicking a grey folder I get this window
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJinB.png)

However, when I right click a blue folder to do the same thing I get this single file instead
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZrkP.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blue folder is a folder reference. You might want to convert the folder reference to an actual folder. Rightclick it and open it in finder, you will see that the path is different than in your project view. You can drag it into your project and tick 'Create groups'. You can also tick 'Copy items if needed' if wanted.

You also could create a storyboard on a different destination and than drag it into the desired folder reference.